# google prediction api java

Tags: java, google-api, prediction

I need to make a project with data mining for different currencies(ex. EUR, USD) for a period of time, like 30 days/90 days. I wanna take these data from a bank site and try to predict the values they could have in the future, based on the dates that i have. Searching on the internet i found a lot of information, but i don t know which is the best. I found the Google Prediction APi, Weka or other algorithms for different transactions. I want to make the project in java, but for google api i didn't found examples to help me.

Could you give me an advise on what should i use?

Comment: Depends on which coding language you're comfortable with. I would start with that.

Comment: @MaxPD i would like to work with java, i am that an expert but i am willing to learn with every project new things.

Comment: Firstly, get the dataset you want to analyse. Analyse it well. Pre-process it. Then see which algorithm will suit for the type of answers you want. There are heaps of algorithms, you can even create your own, but thats another level.

Comment: @MaxPD i took already from the site, an xml file for 10 days: i have the currencies values for 10 days.